# Square of Numbers in Nested List Python 3

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists

The problem I have to solve is one that takes a nested list as an input, and returns the same nested list, except each element is the square of the element that previously existed in that spot. This is my code

```
>>> def treemap(lst):
...     for element in lst:
...         if element == type(list):
...             return treemap(element)
...         else:
...             element=element**2
...     return lst
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, [4, [5, 6], 7]]
>>> print(treemap(lst))
```

Now I am getting an error that is saying 'int' object is not iterable. I'm assuming that means that it's trying to run the loop for an integer type, which doesn't make sense to me, given that I only rerun the function for those of list types.

Comment: Your if statement is incorrect. It should be if type(element) == list:

Comment: To check for type, you should use: `if isinstance(element, list):`

Comment: Why is it important that I use isinstance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Do not `return` in the recursive call, you will cease processing all remaining elements once you return
2. `element == type(list)` is incorrect, because `type(list)` is `<class 'type'>` which will never be equal to any item in your list. Use `isinstance` instead
3. In the base case, you'll need to access the element by index to have changes reflected

---

```
def treemap(lst):
    for i, element in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(element, list):
            treemap(element)
        else:
            lst[i] = lst[i]**2
    return lst
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 9, [16, [25, 36], 49]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution generates a *new* list using a recursive, ternary list comprehension that recurses on itself if the item `n` is iterable, otherwise it returns its square.

```
def square_list(lst):
    return [square_list(n) if hasattr(n, '__iter__') else n ** 2 for n in lst]

>>> square_list(lst)
[1, 4, 9, [16, [25, 36], 49]]
```

**EDIT**

It is a *ternary* list comprehension:

```
[a if condition(x) else b for x in some_iterable]

# Where condition(x) returns True if condition with argument `x` is True, otherwise False.
```

*Conditional* list comprehension:

```
[x for x in some_iterable if condition]
```

Comment: Note that this fails under some subtle cases, try e.g. `[np.array(0)]` as input.

Comment: I didn't even know conditional list comprehension was a thing. This is a really neat way of solving it! I could have had the same answer has yours except with isinstance(n, list) then?

Comment: @JonasAdler I don't believe `np.array(0)` is a valid constructor (it works for `np.array([0])`.  The value `0` is not array-like. array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order=None, subok=False, ndmin=0)

Create an array.

Parameters
----------
object : array_like
    An array, any object exposing the array interface, an
    object whose __array__ method returns an array, or any
    (nested) sequence.

Comment: `np.array(0)` creates a zero dimensional array. Perhaps I should be more clear, calling your code with that gives "`TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array`"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `isinstance()` to check for `type`, and if the element is a list instead of returning `treemap(element)` you can assign `a[i]` to `treemap(element)` which will run recursively until all the elements are processed. For example:

```
def treemap(lst):
    for i, element in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(element, list):
            lst[i] = treemap(element)
        else:
            lst[i] = element ** 2
    return lst

lst=[1 ,2 , 3, [ 4, [ 5, 6 ], 7 ] ]
print(treemap(lst))
```

output:

```
[1, 4, 9, [16, [25, 36], 49]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using a single list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, [4, [5, 6], 7]]
>>> [(lambda f, x: f(f, x))(lambda g, x: [g(g, y) for y in x] if isinstance(x, list) else x ** 2, el) for el in lst]
[1, 4, 9, [16, [25, 36], 49]]
```

Not that I would recommend anyone to use this under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

```
def treemap(f, tree):
    def branchmap(branch):
        # map on branches
        # if it is a branch (a list), treat it as a smaller tree
        # else it is a leave (a number), apply the function on the leave
        return treemap(f, branch) if type(branch) is list else f(branch)
    return list(map(branchmap, tree))

def square(x):
    return x*x

def square_tree(tree):
    return treemap(square, tree)

square_tree([1,[2,3,[4, 5, 6], 7],[8, 9]])
-->>
[1, [4, 9, [16, 25, 36], 49], [64, 81]]
```

Comment: Neat way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

So as to stay as close to my code as possible, using everyone's suggestions, here is my answer:

> 1) 1==type(int) is False, the correct way is type(1)==int
>
> 2) Changing the element's value does not change the list, so I would need to 
>       refer to the index of lst and change its value
>
> 3) I should not return the recursive function, but just call it. A return 
>       statement passes a value back to the immediate caller of the current 
>       function's call-frame, which is not what I want.

Therefore, my final answer is this,

```
>>> def treemap(lst):
...     for i in range(len(lst)):
...         if type(lst[i])==int:
...             lst[i]=lst[i]**2
...         elif type(lst[i])==list:
...             treemap(lst[i])
...     return lst
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, [4, [5, 6], 7]]
>>> print(treemap(lst))
[1, 4, 9, [16, [25, 36], 49]]
```

Answer (score 0):

there are answers provide solutions that in_place change the lst, i'll provide a solution that return a copy of original list.

```
def treemap(lst):
    cp = list()
    for element in lst:
        if isinstance(element, list):
            cp.append(treemap(element))
        else:
            cp.append(element**2)
    return cp
```